# Inequality related to Inner Product and Permutation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, permutations

I think I've seen this from one of my undergraduate linear algebra textbook, but I cannot find it now. Is this true? If it is, how can we prove it?

---

Given column vectors $\mathbf x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^T$ and $\mathbf y=(y_1,\cdots,y_n)^T$ where
$x_1\geq \cdots \geq x_n\geq 0$ and $y_1\geq \cdots \geq y_n\geq 0$,
$$\mathbf x^T \mathbf P \mathbf y \leq \mathbf x^T \mathbf y$$
where $\mathbf P$ is a [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

For example, say $\mathbf x = (3,2,1)^T$, $\mathbf y=(9,2,1)^T$, and $\mathbf P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

1. $\mathbf x^T \mathbf P \mathbf y = 1\cdot 9 + 3\cdot 2 + 2\cdot 1 = 17$.
2. $\mathbf x^T \mathbf y = 3\cdot 9 + 2\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 1 = 32$.

Hence, the claim is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well-known Rearrangement inequality (see, for instance, the [paper](http://webfile.ru/6580758) by K.Wu and Andy Liu).